# How to add (" ") to all the words i have in my String Array in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, cpu-word

How to add (`" "`) to all the words i have in my `String` Array in eclipse?

Suppose, If i have like 100 countries name as data is it possible that i copy paste them to my

```
private static String[] countries = {};
```

and then any technique to add (`" "`) to all of the words inside the array?

Comment: do you want to do this through code or do you want to hard code it into the array?

Comment: find & replace ? find all occurences of '",' (thats separating the strings), replace with ' ",'

Comment: No i dont want the (" ")s in my outputs. If i take any string array i must give (" ") to the inside datas. Like private static String[] countries = {"USA","UK"}... But suppose if i have USA,UK is there any technique i can copy paste them and the (" ")s can be added to all at once rather than typing to every individual one.

Comment: So what you really want to do is add quotes to all the countries on a list you have outside of Eclipse? How about reading the countries from a file?

Comment: You need a loop, there is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use edit -> find/replace to change all the spaces to an expression like ", "

Comment: or all the commas! So just copy paste the content of your list `USA,UK` and replace all `,` with `","`

Answer (score 0):

Find \n Replace with  "\n"

when you replace make sure you selected "Regular expression is on"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `" "` to your arrays, you will need to add a forward slash in front of a quotation mark within your array element. An example of this would be:

```
static String[] countries={"\"CountryA\"", "\"CountryB\"", etc...};
```

**Output**
Instead of:
CountryA
CountryB

The new output will be 
"CountryA"
"CountryB"

I hope this is what you are asking for....

Answer (score 0):

Do this, example you have to write America, Canada as counties , write :-

private static string[] countries = {"\"America\"","\"Canada\"}; 
Output will be "America" "Canada"

because to write " anywhere you have to use it with a slash\ like \" it will give ".